# Is $\exp(x-x_0) = \exp(x)\cdot \exp(-x_0)$?

Tags: exponential-function

I try to do the integral of $\exp(x-x_0)$. 
However, I am not sure that if it is true that $$\exp(x-x_0) = \exp(x)\cdot\exp(-x_0)$$ I don't think it is $$\dfrac{\exp(x)}{\exp(x_0)}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\exp(x-x_0)= \exp(x)\exp(-x_0)= \frac{\exp(x)}{\exp(x_0)}$$

Comment: The user has edited the question, @SiongThyeGoh.

Comment: thanks, from the edit history, seems like it is an unintentional change in the title.